# Calling function in C++

Tags: c++, function, call, cout

I'm trying to call a function with no return type but it doesn't seem to be getting called.

The code looks something like this(summarized):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int ItemsInQuestion[4];

void GetQuestions(int NumQuests);


int main()
{
    int NumberOfQuestions = 0;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    cout << "How many questions would you like?" << endl;
    cin >> NumberOfQuestions;
    cout << NumberOfQuestions << " questions will be asked.";
    GetQuestions(NumberOfQuestions);
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}

void GetQuestions(int NumQuests)
{
    for(int Questions=NumQuests; Questions>NumQuests; Questions++)
    {
        ItemsInQuestion[0]=(rand()%(263))+1;
        ItemsInQuestion[1]=(rand()%(263))+1;
        ItemsInQuestion[2]=(rand()%(263))+1;
        ItemsInQuestion[3]=(rand()%(263))+1;
        cout << ItemsInQuestion[0] << ' ' << ItemsInQuestion[1] << ' ' <<ItemsInQuestion[2] << ' ' << ItemsInQuestion[3];
    }
}
```

The line that outputs the values in the array never comes up. What is causing this?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but as an constructive advice: Use a debugger. You do use a debugger, don't you? :-) In such a case I would go through the functions step by step and see that the function is called but the for-loop is skipped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because

```
 int Questions=NumQuests;
```

and

```
 Questions>NumQuests;
```

don't like each other.

You set `Questions` to `NumQuests` and then tell the loop to keep going as long as `Questions` is strictly greater than `NumQuests`, which it isn't to start off with.

Even if it was, you'd soon run into an overflow and **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way of using for-loops :

```
for ( __Initialization, __Condition, __Increment)
```

As Grigore pointed out in his answer, your initialization is wrong. As `Questions=NumQuest`, the statement `Questions>NumQuests` is false from the beginning, and your code is equivalent to

```
for ( ; 1<1 ; ) // I'm a lazy loop, I'm ugly and useless
```

There is an infinite number of way to do what you want :

```
// Direct : 0, 1, 2, .. NumQuest-1.
for (int Questions=0 ; Questions < NumQuests ; Questions++) 
{ ... } 
// Reverse : NumQuest, ..., 2, 1.
for (int Questions=NumQuests ; Questions > 0 ; Questions--)
{ ... }
```